# How to count NAs using terra's global function?

Tags: r, raster, na, terra

I am trying to count the non-NA values in a spatRaster using the `global()` function from the terra package. All the functions (mean, max, sd, etc.) seem to work except for `"isNA"` and `"notNA"`. For these two functions it returns this error: `Error in fun(values(x[[i]]), ...) : could not find function "fun"`, which is the same error it returns for a misspelled/non-existent function.

```
r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10)
values(r) <- c(1:(ncell(r)-1),NA) # Add one NA value
global(r, fun="mean", na.rm=TRUE) # works
global(r, fun="notNA") # error
global(r, fun="notAfunction") # error
```

Interestingly, when looking at the documentation (`?global`), the NA functions are named in the function description but are not listed specifically listed as argument options for `fun`.

So can `global()` count the NAs/non-NAs? Are the NA function names correct?

Edit:
terra version: 1.4.22

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your version of `terra` is likely outdated and does not include the functions `isNA` or `notNA`. You can see the functions in the source code of the current version at [Terra raster methods](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/e115c246fb7ac94c112bf02c3d99454065cf8be4/src/raster_methods.cpp#L2551) (lines 2551 to 2639 for the `global` function).

I am currently running version `1.5.21`, and the functions work fine.

```
packageVersion("terra")
#[1] ‘1.5.21’

global(r, fun="isNA")
#      isNA
#lyr.1    1

global(r, fun="notNA")
#      notNA
#lyr.1    99
```

You can update the package and reload the library with the following:

```
install.packages("terra")
library(terra)
```

Answer (score 3):

When I run your code, it actually works:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10)
values(r) <- c(1:(ncell(r)-1),NA) 
global(r, fun="mean", na.rm=TRUE)
global(r, fun="isNA")
global(r, fun="notNA")
```

Output of `isNA`:

```
      isNA
lyr.1    1
```

Output of `notNA`:

```
      notNA
lyr.1    99
```

Comment: That is odd. I just copied and ran the code from what you posted to double check and I'm still getting errors for the two NA functions but the mean works fine. Any ideas what the difference might be?

Comment: @ia200 What version of `terra` are you running? Maybe you have an outdated version that doesn't include those functions? It works for me too, when running version `1.5.21`. To check your version, you can run `packageVersion("terra")`.

Comment: I'm on 1.4.22 so I'll try updating to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGB, that did solve the issue. If you post an answer I'll accept it.